# Elasticksearch query in stack alerts not exist

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to monitor a list of keywords in a certain index and write these events in a new index
after a little search, I found the way for that using Elasticsearch query in stack alerts but I can't find it
I found the index threshold only under Elasticsearch query.
so how to enable Elasticsearch query.
Kibana version 7.11.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kibana version  7.11.2 doesn't support Elasticksearch query in stack alerts we have to upgrade kibana version to be 7.16